# How to install calibri font into debian 12?

Tags: debian, package-management, fonts

I need for my php excel creator library, the Calibri font.

I tried installing this: https://packages.debian.org/search?keywords=ttf-mscorefonts-installer

But it has not installed the calibri

```
Extracting cabinet: andale32.exe
  extracting fontinst.inf
  extracting andale.inf
  extracting fontinst.exe
  extracting AndaleMo.TTF
  extracting ADVPACK.DLL
  extracting W95INF32.DLL
  extracting W95INF16.DLL

All done, no errors.
arialb32.exe: OK
Extracting cabinet: arialb32.exe
  extracting fontinst.exe
  extracting fontinst.inf
  extracting AriBlk.TTF

All done, no errors.
arial32.exe: OK
Extracting cabinet: arial32.exe
  extracting FONTINST.EXE
  extracting fontinst.inf
  extracting Ariali.TTF
  extracting Arialbd.TTF
  extracting Arialbi.TTF
  extracting Arial.TTF

All done, no errors.
comic32.exe: OK
Extracting cabinet: comic32.exe
  extracting fontinst.inf
  extracting Comicbd.TTF
  extracting Comic.TTF
  extracting fontinst.exe

All done, no errors.
courie32.exe: OK
Extracting cabinet: courie32.exe
  extracting cour.ttf
  extracting courbd.ttf
  extracting courbi.ttf
  extracting fontinst.inf
  extracting couri.ttf
  extracting fontinst.exe

All done, no errors.
georgi32.exe: OK
Extracting cabinet: georgi32.exe
  extracting fontinst.inf
  extracting Georgiaz.TTF
  extracting Georgiab.TTF
  extracting Georgiai.TTF
  extracting Georgia.TTF
  extracting fontinst.exe

All done, no errors.
impact32.exe: OK
Extracting cabinet: impact32.exe
  extracting fontinst.exe
  extracting Impact.TTF
  extracting fontinst.inf

All done, no errors.
times32.exe: OK
Extracting cabinet: times32.exe
  extracting fontinst.inf
  extracting Times.TTF
  extracting Timesbd.TTF
  extracting Timesbi.TTF
  extracting Timesi.TTF
  extracting FONTINST.EXE

All done, no errors.
trebuc32.exe: OK
Extracting cabinet: trebuc32.exe
  extracting FONTINST.EXE
  extracting trebuc.ttf
  extracting Trebucbd.ttf
  extracting trebucbi.ttf
  extracting trebucit.ttf
  extracting fontinst.inf

All done, no errors.
verdan32.exe: OK
Extracting cabinet: verdan32.exe
  extracting fontinst.exe
  extracting fontinst.inf
  extracting Verdanab.TTF
  extracting Verdanai.TTF
  extracting Verdanaz.TTF
  extracting Verdana.TTF

All done, no errors.
webdin32.exe: OK
Extracting cabinet: webdin32.exe
  extracting fontinst.exe
  extracting Webdings.TTF
  extracting fontinst.inf
  extracting Licen.TXT

All done, no errors.
```

Comment: I don't think Calibri can be installed (legally) on non-Windows systems. See https://wiki.debian.org/SubstitutingCalibriAndCambriaFonts.